JavaScript is not working as per our expectation in transforming the card from its original position
I have multiple card in the card_section, and in card there is also a div named card_img. I was writing a query for each card that when we click on any card the card_img changes its position to the left of card_section through the transform property, but its parent means card doesn't change its position. But in this, we don't know how many card are there in a single row so we make a function getCardsPerRow to calculate how many cards are there in a row then finally if the width of card_section changes, the function of getCardsPerRow also changes.
My submission is that my queries are working fine for first row whether it has 2 card, 3 card, or 5 card, but in the second row, it is not working as expected.
Following are the code:


// Function to calculate the number of cards per row dynamically
function getCardsPerRow() {
  const cardSection = document.querySelector(".card_section");
  const card = document.querySelector(".card");

  if (!card || !cardSection) return 1; // Default to 1 if elements are not found

  const containerWidth = cardSection.offsetWidth;

  const cardStyle = getComputedStyle(card);
  const cardWidth = card.offsetWidth;
  const cardMarginLeft = parseFloat(cardStyle.marginLeft);
  const cardMarginRight = parseFloat(cardStyle.marginRight);
  const totalCardWidth = cardWidth + cardMarginLeft + cardMarginRight;

  return Math.floor(containerWidth / totalCardWidth);
}

// Main script
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
const root = document.documentElement; // Refers to :root in CSS

// Function to update the card behaviors dynamically
function setupCardTransformations() {
  const cardsPerRow = getCardsPerRow(); // Calculate cards per row dynamically

  cards.forEach((card, index) => {
    card.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const columnIndex = index % cardsPerRow; // Column index (0, 1, 2, etc.)
      const rowIndex = Math.floor(index / cardsPerRow); // Row index (0, 1, 2, etc.)

      // Calculate offsets based on column position
      const offsetPercent = -100 * columnIndex; // Percentage offset for column
      const offsetPixel = -20 * columnIndex; // Pixel offset for column

      // Update CSS variables dynamically
      root.style.setProperty("--offset-percent", `${offsetPercent}%`);
      root.style.setProperty("--offset-pixel", `${offsetPixel}px`);

      // Add transform class to clicked card
      const img = card.querySelector(".card_img");
      img.classList.toggle("transform_to_left");

      // Optionally remove the class from other cards
      cards.forEach((otherCard) => {
        if (otherCard !== card) {
          otherCard.querySelector(".card_img").classList.remove(
            "transform_to_left");
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

// Initialize card transformations and update on resize
setupCardTransformations();
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  setupCardTransformations(); // Recalculate and rebind the logic on resize
});
.team_main_container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

.team_main_container .team_cards_container {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

.team_main_container .team_cards_container .card_section {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.team_main_container .team_cards_container .card_section .card {
  width: calc((100% / 6) - 16px);
  height: 30rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.team_main_container .team_cards_container .card_section .card .card_img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #2b2525;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #45ba00;
}

:root {
  --offset-percent: 0%;
  /* Default percentage offset */
  --offset-pixel: 0px;
  /* Default pixel offset */
}

.team_main_container .team_cards_container .card_section .card .card_img.transform_to_left {
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--offset-percent) + var(--offset-pixel)));
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  /* Add a smooth transition */
}
<div class="team_main_container">
  <div class="team_cards_container">
    <div class="card_section">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_img">Card 1 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_img">Card 2 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_img">Card 3 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_img">Card 4 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_img">Card 5 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_img">Card 6 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_img">Card 7 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_img">Card 8 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_img">Card 9 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_img">Card 10 </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




This sounds like a bit of a nightmare.  Can you show an image of what exactly you're trying to do?  Most likely, you shouldn't be adjusting the position of things in JavaScript.  Leave that to the layout engine in the browser to figure out.

@Brad is it possible to show you live?

No, you need to put the information in your question.  Otherwise, how can anyone else learn from this example once you've solved it?

@Brad I am not able to add images because stackoverflow tells me "You can only post 1 time each day due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience. See the help center for more."

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you [edit] your question and explain the overall objective with the application and add a [mre] to show what it should look like.

You can also leave a comment to your question with a link to a descriptive/demonstrative image, one of us can then edit that image into the question on your behalf.

@DavidThomas I am not even able to save the post without including anything.

@DavidThomas Can you please tell me how to use or implement Run Code Snippet?

@DavidThomas This is my demonstration layout-
Following is the Original layout without clicking any card
[Original layout without clicking any card][1]
Following is the layout by clicked on card 4-
[After clicked on card 4][2]   Please add this.

Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?

@jabaa Where did I say, "Can anyone help me?" ?

@jabaa Why did you give me -1 vote? I am not posting anything outside of the rule.

Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform with the goal to collect questions and answers to help future users with similar questions. There is no question but "Please help me to solve this query." That's not helpful for future users. When you hover the downvote button, you can find downvote reasons. One of them is, that the question isn't helpful.

@jabaa OK, I will remove it and I also remember this in future posts. Thanks in advance. Can you please correct my vote?

You could edit the question and fix it. Then, I would remove the downvote. But why would I remove the downvote if you want to delete the question?

@jabaa I am trying but it shows me this- "You can only post 1 time each day due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience. See the help center for more.". Can you please tell me how can I edit it?

You can fix it tomorrow.

@jabaa I have deleted what you have told me to do.

I've asked you to add a specific question. This is a question and answer platform for specific questions and I can't find a question here.

@jabaa You are mad and this platform is also very bad. People don't know what they comment on without reading the whole post. They just demotivate the beginners. Anyway, I have solved my issue. And I don't need you as well as the people like you to solve my problems.

@Jabaa If you have the right to block my ID then you are free to do so, I don't need this type of disgusting forum where people are busy pointing out grammatical mistakes, and typo errors instead of solving the questions.

I think one problem is the misunderstanding that this is not a beginners help platform. It's a question and answer platform for specific questions. How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? You are expected to debug and isolate your problem and formulate a clear and specific question, not dump your code and ask others to debug it for you.

@jabaa My word "beginner" means that the person who uses something for the first time is a beginner of that thing. I am new on this forum but I am not new in my field. By the way, you did me a favor by seeing my writings and not solving my question, as a result of which I increased my experience by solving my question myself. Thank you so much.
